# Complete Scala Class parameters depeding on its type

Tags: scala

I have a Class in Scala like:

```
class Person(age: Int, name: String, ageYesterday: Int)
```

I would like to complete the parameters of the class, depending on the type:

- All `Int` parameters as `3`
- All `String` parameters as `"Michael"`

I was thinking of making a for loop that goes through the different types of the Class but i have not been able to find a way to list the different type of the parameters of a Class. It is possible to do or I should just complete parameters manually?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

> loop that goes through the different types of the Class

Note that *loop* phenomena exists in the world of runtime, whilst *type* phenomena exists is the world of compile-time. These two worlds exists in different timelines. Crossing the border between them usually involves advanced techniques such as reflection.

Maybe try removing some boilerplate via `apply` factory in the companion like so

```
case class Person(age: Int, name: String, ageYesterday: Int, nameYesterday: String)
object Person {
  def apply(defaultInt: Int = 3, defaultString: String = "Michael") = 
    new Person(defaultInt, defaultString, defaultInt, defaultString)
}
Person()
// res0: Person = Person(3,Michael,3,Michael)
```

or here is something fun you should not do

```
case class Person(age: Int, name: String, ageYesterday: Int, nameYesterday: String)
object Person {
  def default[T](implicit ev: T =:= Int): Int = 3
  def default[T](implicit ev: T =:= String): String = "Michael"
  def apply() = new Person(default, default, default, default)
}
Person()
// res0: Person = Person(3,Michael,3,Michael)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) to generate an instance of case class

```
import shapeless.ops.hlist.FillWith
import shapeless.{Generic, HList, Poly0} 

object defaultPoly extends Poly0 {
  implicit val int: Case0[Int] = at(3)
  implicit val string: Case0[String] = at("Michael")
}

def makeInstance[A] = new PartiallyApplied[A]
class PartiallyApplied[A] {
  def apply[L <: HList]()(implicit 
    gen: Generic.Aux[A, L], 
    fill: FillWith[defaultPoly.type, L]): A = gen.from(fill())
}

case class Person(age: Int, name: String, ageYesterday: Int)

makeInstance[Person]() //Person(3,Michael,3)
```

or [macro annotation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations.html) to complete default values of class fields

```
import scala.annotation.{StaticAnnotation, compileTimeOnly}
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

@compileTimeOnly("enable macro paradise")
class default[A] extends StaticAnnotation {
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*): Any = macro DefaultMacro.impl
}

object DefaultMacro {
  def impl(c: blackbox.Context)(annottees: c.Tree*): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._
    annottees match {
      case q"$mods class $tpname[..$tparams] $ctorMods(...$paramss) extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents { $self => ..$stats }" :: tail =>
        val paramss1 = paramss.map(_.map{
          case q"$mods val $tname: $tpt = $EmptyTree" =>
            q"$mods val $tname: $tpt = _root_.scala.Predef.implicitly[Default[$tpt]].value"
          case valDef => valDef
        })
        q"""
            $mods class $tpname[..$tparams] $ctorMods(...$paramss1) extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents { $self => ..$stats }
            ..$tail
           """
    }
  }
}

class Default[A](val value: A)
object Default {
  implicit val int: Default[Int] = new Default(3)
  implicit val string: Default[String] = new Default("Michael")
}

@default
case class Person(age: Int, name: String, ageYesterday: Int)

//Warning:scalac: {
//  case class Person extends scala.Product with scala.Serializable {
//    <caseaccessor> <paramaccessor> val age: Int = _;
//    <caseaccessor> <paramaccessor> val name: String = _;
//    <caseaccessor> <paramaccessor> val ageYesterday: Int = _;
//    def <init>(age: Int = _root_.scala.Predef.implicitly[Default[Int]].value, name: String = _root_.scala.Predef.implicitly[Default[String]].value, ageYesterday: Int = _root_.scala.Predef.implicitly[Default[Int]].value) = {
//      super.<init>();
//      ()
//    }
//  };
//  ()
//}

new Person() //Person(3,Michael,3)
```